# Laravel - How to Transform Raw Query to Eloquent in Laravel

Tags: laravel

How do I transform my raw query to Laravel Eloquent

I want to transform

```
        $games = DB::table('game_point')
                     ->select('game_point.game_name','game_point.description','game_point.point_assigned', DB::raw("DATE(game_point.created_at) as created_at"))
                       ->paginate(15);
```

to

```
$games= new GamePoint();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To try this,
Here you change your date format in Date() function.

```
$data = GamePoint::select('game_point.game_name','game_point.description','game_point.point_assigned','game_point.created_at')->paginate(15);   

foreach($data as $key => $val){
   $data[$key]->created_at = Date('Y-m-d',strtotime($data[$key]->created_at)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly change it by using `date()` in `blade` or in controller depend upon your usage.
try the following code

```
$data = GamePoint::select('game_point.game_name','game_point.description','game_point.point_assigned','game_point.created_at')->paginate(15);
```

Or In the blade or contrller you can use it just paste it where you using inside `foreach`

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime($user->from_date));
```

Or you can use `carbon` which is already included in laravel for working with date and time.

You can read about this package [here](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Answer (score 0):

try below:

```
$games = GamePoint::paginate(15);
```